# Why is my Ford Ecosport petrol engine sputtering sporadically?

Tags: ford, gasoline, acceleration

I have a 2013 Ford Ecosport 1.0L petrol engine. It is turbocharged. Recently, around the time of my 120000 km service, I noticed that the car would sporadically sputter. The sputtering happens at different speeds, different gears, and at differing acceleration. The problem comes and goes from day to day (some days I do not experience it). I mentioned it at the 120000 km service (done by a Ford service centre), but they did not pick anything up in their diagnostic test. I though maybe the service would sort it out but the problem persists, but is unpredictable and cannot necessarily be reliably demonstrated to a mechanic. Any ideas what I could ask them to check?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you tell us what vehicle this is? Would there be any way to get a video of what you're talking about? Your "sporadically sputter" might not equate to mine, so showing us what's going on would go a long way.

Comment: It's a 2013 Ford Ecosport, with a 1.0L turbocharged petrol engine. Perhaps sputtering isn't the right word; the car is jerking on acceleration. It is not possible to get a video, because it is only something that can be felt, but not seen or heard.

Comment: My apologies as I'd not heard of the Ecosport before (though I should have!). How hard is the jerking on acceleration (I realize this is subjective)? Is this a manual or automatic? I'm thinking about the only way you are going to be able to sort this is to be monitoring the system through data logging. It might be the only way to get a clue what's going on.

Comment: It is a manual. I took it to a Ford workshop, and they have indicated that the fuel injectors are leaking and need replacement. What I wanted to ascertain, from a mechanical point of view, is why leaking fuel injectors would cause sporadic jerking as opposed to jerking every single time I drive?